# How can you read numbers from keyboard until CTRL+D is pressed?

Tags: c

As the title says, I need to read numbers until CTRL+D is pressed. I was thinking about getchar() but i need to separate negative numbers from positive ones and i think it will be quite complicated like that.

Comment: You can't do that with `getchar` unless you build the number yourself. I suggest `fgets` and then apply `sscanf` to the string read.

Comment: What you have done so far on this?

Comment: Ctrl-D is indicating EOF on some terminals. So you will need to read input until EOF is seen.

Comment: `int n; char buf[99]; while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &n) != 1) /* error */; /* use n */ }`

Comment: do not read you number character per character by yourself, it is more simple to use _scanf_ to read the number, _getchar_ can be used to bypass invalid characters and to detect EOF, look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use *scanf* to try to read a number (here I suppose *int*), and *getchar* (or equivalent) to both bypass non valid characters for a number and to detect EOF :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  for (;;) {
    int v;

    if (scanf("%d", &v) == 1)
      printf("read %d\n", v);
    else
      // bypass invalid char
      if (getchar() == EOF)
        break;
  }

  puts("done");
}
```

Compilation end executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
12 aze -23
read 12
read -23
   3 e
read 3
done
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Under raspberrypi I enter two consecutive <kbd>control-d</kbd> to indicate EOF

Using *echo* to also produce the EOF :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo "123 aze -23 " | ./a.out
read 123
read -23
done
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

When there is an invalid character I chosen to read only one character, it is also possible to bypass the rest of the line, or stop to read numbers, it is a choice.